# SDI-12 protocol, working with SoftwareSerial

Tags: sensors, interrupt, timers

I have a `Teros 11` moisture sensor that I have managed to make it work with the `SDI-12` arduino library.

However, this library does not work with `SoftwareSerial` and this is critical for me.
There is a known open issue in Github for years, located here: https://github.com/EnviroDIY/Arduino-SDI-12/issues/8

A person claims to have mitigated the issue by commenting out some code that should be omitted, specifically code of extra interrupts.

The changes are committed  in a separate branch here:
https://github.com/EnviroDIY/Arduino-SDI-12/pull/84/commits/4def0046eb8d465c4079b3115aade50d3ff85b4d

I made the change myself, but while the code compiles fine now (along with the `SoftwareSerial` library), the data that I get back from the sensor is junk.

Does anyone know this issue, or can understand what happens? The code that is being left out is only a few lines, so if anyone could take a look, I would greatly appreciate this.

Comment: `can understand what happens` ... one child grabs all of the crayons

Comment: @jsotola I don't get you, sorry....

Comment: software serial grabs all of the interrupts

Comment: @jsotola Even the third interrupt?